# Web Audio API not playing on iOS version 13.3. Works on older versions of iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web-audio-api

I have an audio visualizer I made using the web audio API. It works on PC, and it did work on iOS until I updated to 13.3.

I don't know what is causing it not to work. All I know is that it only happens on the newer versions of iOS.

Here is my jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/r1dobj07/

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var audio = new Audio();
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = false;
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

audio.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
audio.src = "https://greggman.github.io/doodles/sounds/DOCTOR VOX - Level Up.mp3";
//audio.play();
audio.controls = true;

document.getElementById("wrapper").append(audio);

var player = document.getElementById('audio_player');
var context = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
src.connect(analyser);
analyser.fftSize = 32;
analyser.connect(context.destination);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;


var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);


var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 0.5;
var barHeight;
var x = 0;


function renderFrame() {
  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
  x = 0;
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
    barHeight = dataArray[i];
    if (barHeight === 0) {
      barHeight = 20;
    }
    var barHeightScaled = barHeight / 250;
    var barHeightScaled2 = barHeightScaled * HEIGHT;
    var newHeight = HEIGHT - barHeightScaled2;
    var r = 111;
    var g = 121;
    var b = 180;

    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect = function(x, y, w, h, r) {
      if (w < 2 * r) r = w / 2;
      if (h < 2 * r) r = h / 2;
      this.beginPath();
      this.moveTo(x + r, y);
      this.arcTo(x + w, y, x + w, y + h, r);
      this.arcTo(x + w, y + h, x, y + h, r);
      this.arcTo(x, y + h, x, y, r);
      this.arcTo(x, y, x + w, y, r);
      this.closePath();
      return this;
    }


    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    ctx.roundRect(x, newHeight / 2, barWidth, barHeightScaled2, 50).fill();

    x += barWidth + 4;
  }
}

renderFrame();
```

}

);

On PC it works fine. On my iPhone, it doesn't play the audio. I can see the bars are rendered on iOS, but they aren't moving, as no audio is being outputted.

Comment: In iOS, Silent Mode needs to be set to off to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently a [bug in iOS related to the MediaStreamAudioSourceNode](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204261). It causes a MediaElement to stop once you connect it to an AudioContext.

Comment: hrm, I've been looking for solution to get webaudio working as well.. is this the sole reason why nothing seems to work?

Comment: No, Safari features the largest collection of Web Audio bugs. But to be fair Safari is also not officially supporting the Web Audio API as it is still prefixed. I maintain a library which tries to fix as many bugs in userland as possible. Maybe that helps. It's called [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context).

Comment: ah I've seen that library before. Thanks for the reminder and great job ✌

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, my test setup is on iOS 13.6.1. It is very bad! I am a WebAudio expert so here is what I found.

When our music app is set in background mode (user switches to another app or screen turned off), all the WebAudio AudioContexts inside the WkWebView freeze after exactly 27 seconds. At that moment, our app turns silent and the AudioContext.currentTime stops incrementing despite that the AudioContext.state is still "running". That's the only way to detect that broken WebAudio state I found.

And the worst part is that bringing back the app to the foreground don't resuscitate the frozen AudioContexts, they are dead forever, I tried. You can recreate new AudioContexts though but in our case we simply restart all the app, which means the user lost his progress. This is a quick fix waiting for the real iOS fix.

It is obviously a big bug introduced in iOS 13. Also I can see that this issue is almost one year old and it has not been fixed, that's not respectful for all HTML5 developer here, that's sad! Hoping someone competent will take this issue seriously.

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to the question.